# Number of processes needed to maximize CPU utilization under I/O wait conditions

Tags: computer-architecture, cpu

A computer has 2 GB of RAM of which the operating system occupies 256 MB. The processes 
are all 128 MB (for simplicity) and have the same characteristics. If the goal is 99% CPU 
utilization, what is the maximum I/O wait that can be tolerated?

My professor said that there are 14 processes in the memory before proceeding with the solution. Why are there 14 processes?

Comment: Please note that *Explain this to me please* is not a question. It should be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want all processes to fit in memory. If there are $N$ processes, then together with the OS they take up $256+128N$ megabytes. Since there is only room for $2048$ megabytes, we need $256+128N \leq 2048$. Dividing by $128$, this is $N+2 \leq 16$.

Comment: And the memory needs to be full because that allows the greatest number of processes (13) to be waiting for I/O while still being able to run at least one process. And that, in turn, allows for the greatest possible I/O wait time, since there are many processes to wait in parallel.